# Node module with Helper file results in 'cannot find module' error when installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Apologies in advance, I'm sure there's a simple answer in an obvious thread I've just failed to find it/understand it.

Given a node.js module `Jimmy` implemented in the global `node_modules/Jimmy/index.js` file; I have a few 'helper' functions that I put in a separate `Helper.js` file, all in the same directory. Works great when I run a sample program `require`ing it from the same directory, but running that same sample program from anywhere else, it fails to load the supporting Helper.js file:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'Helper'
```

Can someone explain or point me to an explanation of why this doesn't work and what I should be doing to make it work?

Edit: Dumbed it down to just demo the problem. Including the Swagger-client dependency just in case that matters.

Node Module is called Jimmy in the directory `~/Jimmy`.

Module class defined in `~/Jimmy/index.js`:

```
var Swagger = require('swagger-client');
var Helper  = require('Helper');
function Jimmy (host, username, password) {
    this._host = host;
    this._hdr = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new     Buffer(username+':'+password).toString('base64') ,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
}
Jimmy.prototype.getEntity = function(entity) {
    return Helper.get(this._host, this._hdr, entity);
}
module.exports =
{
    Jimmy: Jimmy
};
```

Module helper function defined in `~/Jimmy/Helper.js`:

```
var Swagger = require('swagger-client');
function get(host, hdr, entity) {
    var url = 'http://'+host+'/config/' + entity;
    var request = {
        url    : url,
        headers: hdr
    };
    return Swagger.http(request)
        .then( (res) => { return res.body; });
}
module.exports =
{
    get : get
};
```

And sample test in `~/test.js`:

```
var jimmy = require('Jimmy');
var j = new jimmy.Jimmy('192.168.56.151:8080', 'admin', 'admin');
j.getEntity('joey')
    .then( (e) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
    })
    .catch( (err) => { console.log('ERR: ' + err); });
```

Comment: Could you please post your code so we can see what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, found my mistake; in case anybody else makes this, for a local file within the module I made it work by referencing it via a relative pathname.

So in my case where from my module's `index.js` I only wanted the local version of `Helper.js` I wanted:

```
var Helper  = require('./Helper'); // works
```

rather than:

```
var Helper  = require('Helper'); // 'not found' error
```